# Parsing a Data Source Name with Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I've some code which involves a lot of PostgreSQL database connections. This code needs to work both locally (where I've control over my environment variables) and on another server where the environment variable contains a Data Source Name (DSN) for a PostgreSQL server.

I'd ideally like to parse the following:

```
POSTGRES_PROD('host=.... database=... username=... password=...')
```

and assign these to 4 seperate environment variables.

I tried using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dsnparse/ however this didn't work for this usecase.

Do I just hack together some regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incidentally for this string

`dict(s.split("=") for s in vals.split())` works a la 
[convert dsn string in python to kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857551/convert-dsn-string-in-python-to-kwargs)